# How to integrate Angular to sharepoint?

Tags: web-part, angular2

My current approach is to build the angular app (Angular 6 at the time)
To re declare index.html as index.aspx
Place inside a directory in sharepoint.

Then in front page, add a web part: Media and Content -> Page Viewer
and reference the index.aspx

However every update requires me to force a pop cache
So in the webpart, I have to update index.aspx?1  (and so on)
as well as all references inside index.html, like styles, bundle, etc...

Is there an alternative approach? The reason I have to do this I believe is because the sharepoint is optimized to maintain cache and not have to reload.

Comment: Hi why don't you refer your index.html in content editor webpart

Comment: @Sunilsahu, Not sure why, it didn't work. Although it did in the past, it experienced same issue raised here.